# php to javascript variable not working in chrome and I.E

Tags: php, javascript

I am converting a php variable to a javascript variable. It works fine in firefox, but in chrome and I.E it doesn't work,

Here is what I'm doing,

```
var chkimg = "<?= $_imgname ?>";
```

Where $_imgname contains the data and is tested. But it doesn't convert to javascript variable!

Comment: did you `alert` the `chkimg` to see if it's there or not? also could you post a little bit more of your code? if it's working on FF, it should works on others also, because it's just a variable ... my you have a problem in other parts ....

Comment: Yes I did alert! I'm getting data in the php variable and it is confirmed. But it doesn't convert to javascript var in chrome and i.e!

Comment: could you post the exact HTML output of this line? maybe you need to escape some characters, huh?

Answer (score 3):

well please right click on IE, Firefox and Chrome and click view source and go to this line and see what is the difference in all three, that should help you.

Answer (score 1):

try once without using short code.

like `var chkimg = "<?php echo $_imgname; ?>";`

Comment: let me try with my system, and i will give you solution for sure.

Comment: <?php
$_imgname = 'test';
?>

<script>
var chkimg = "<?php echo $_imgname; ?>"; 
alert(chkimg);
</script>

Comment: have u define php variable before js or after it?

Comment: Thanks Vora. I figured out the solution myself!

Comment: Still don't know the issue but i did the thing with differently!